# Expression Blend 2 Issue with Creating Silverlight 2 Projects?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-2.0, expression-blend, blend

I have Expression Blend 2, Service Pack 1, and cannot create a Silverlight 2 project. When I attempt to create a Silverlight 2 project, I get the following error:

> Blend cannot continue because a compatible Silverlight version could not be found.

I installed Blend a few weeks ago, and service packed it yesterday. The order I did things is as follows:

1. "old school" dev stack (VS 2005 Pro, SQL Server 2005 Express, SQL Server Mgmt Studio 2005, Infragistics, etc., all ages ago)
2. Visual Studio 2008 Developer Team Edition
3. SQL Server Management Studio 2008
4. Expression Web 2
5. Expression Blend 2 (2 - 5 were a few weeks ago.)
6. Silverlight SDK 2 (yesterday)
7. Expression Blend 2 SP1 (downloaded then installed, yesterday)
8. Expression Blend 2 SP1 (installed straight from Microsoft site, yesterday, after reading [this](http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/blend/thread/2a58747b-1bd3-4bb3-8073-7d9ef912549b/) and [this](http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/blend/thread/821e1fe9-df0b-4461-bf4b-20ecf6c51088) online.
9. Silverlight Tools for Visual Studio 2008 (yesterday, after giving up on Blend)

Aside from the techniques described in the two links (which I've exhausted, and none have worked), does anyone have any advice? Preferably advice that doesn't involve uninstalling and reinstalling my entire dev stack? :)

Oh, and for what it's worth, I'm on 64-bit Vista. However, Expression is a 32-bit app (and of course the runtime is 32-bit only).

I've posted (essentially) this same question on [Blend's own forums](http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/blend/thread/2442f10d-ac06-4633-a6c3-7e2d1e42681b). If I get a response there that works, I'll post it here in case anyone else ever has this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of Blend do you have installed (version number, not service pack)?

According to [this form posting](http://silverlight.net/forums/t/36181.aspx) the issue gets resolved from:

> The old version of the file also named BlendV2SP1_en.exe has a size of 18,241 KB does NOT work. Microsoft updated this Service Pack somewhere between Oct 16, 2008 in morning and Oct 17 in the morning.

And a more detailed explanation:

> Update Your Blend Version 2.1.1693 to 2.1.1760.0

Also, I didn't see any install of the Silverlight runtime. Do you have that insalled as well?

Comment: Runtime: yes, I do. Forgot to mention that, but it was installed "way back when," then when SL2 went final, I installed that as well. My edition of blend may well be the culprit -- I see 2.1.1693.0; thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Bryant got it, but I want to explain a bit more fully in case anyone else ever gets caught in this trap. Yes, I installed the wrong SP1. (This shouldn't even be possible, but ... whatever.)

I went to the [SP1 page on Microsoft's site](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=EB9B5C48-BA2B-4C39-A1C3-135C60BBBE66&displaylang=en), and read the page. After reading the page, I selected the link which read, "Install Expression Blend 2 SP1."

That was my mistake. That downloads an older version of service pack. (At least as of this writing.)

Clicking the button "Download" at the top of the page instead provides the right service pack, and I appear to be off and running. Sure enough, the version number from the button download is correct, and I was able to create a Silverlight 2 application project now.

Bryant, again, many thanks. (Anyone who even thinks about upvoting this answer should upvote his instead; I should not get the rep, he should.) If I could give you more rep for your answer, I would in a heartbeat.